# Coerce TeXForm("Sqrt(x^2/(z^2+1))") result to a character automatically

Tags: r, class, latex, symbolic-math, yacas

I have  formula that I converted to LaTeX by `Ryacas::TeXForm`. I can`t get from the result character sting that contains LaTeX code, without doing it by hand. 
I tryed:

```
y<-"Sqrt(x^2/(z^2+1))"
Sym(y)
z<-TeXForm(y)
```

I got:

```
"$\sqrt{\frac{x ^{2}}{z ^{2} + 1} }$";
```

But `class(z)` gives both "Sym" and "character"

Then I tried force it to something like 
`w<-"$\sqrt{\frac{x ^{2}}{z ^{2} + 1} }$"` such that:

```
 class(w)
[1] "character"
```

Of course, I can do in just by copying and pasting, but how to do it automatically?

Comment: Using correct answer I found this. If run `w<-yacas(z)[[2]]` then it gives proper result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach via `Ryacas`:

```
> yacas(TeXForm(y))
"$\sqrt{\frac{x ^{2}}{z ^{2} + 1} }$";

> str(yacas(TeXForm(y)))
List of 2
 $          : NULL
 $ YacasForm: chr "\"$\\sqrt{\\frac{x ^{2}}{z ^{2} + 1} }$\";"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "yacas"

> str(yacas(TeXForm(y))$YacasForm)
 chr "\"$\\sqrt{\\frac{x ^{2}}{z ^{2} + 1} }$\";"
```